# dynamically set value in inputtext JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2, user-input

I need to dynamically set value attribute for inputext .I have given example

```
@ManagedBean(name="pageload")
@RequestScoped
public class SearchBean{
    private List<FieldConfigVO> fieldConfig;
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    //getters and setters
}
```

and the FieldConfig object

```
public class FieldConfigVO implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String property_name;
}
```

I need to display in xhtml as

```
<h:dataTable value = "#{pageload.fieldConfig}" var="field">
  <h:column>
    <h:outputText value = "#{field.name}"/>
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <h:inputText value = "#{pageload.??????????/>
  </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

I want to bind the inputText values to the property in the SearchBean.name can be get from FieldConfigVO .something like this in value attribute

value = "#{pageload.+fieldConfigVO.property_name} the values should be set to property1,property2
it can be identified using the property_name

any help please

Answer (score 0):

If all the list's elements are binding to the same managed bean's field: `property1`, then you can access to it naturally by :

```
<h:column>
     <h:inputText value ="#{pageload.property1} />
</h:column>
```

Knowing that the field `property1` is initialized, and has its `getter/setter`.

Comment: it is binded to different properties which can be determined during run time

Comment: But in the end, that's those properties which will store the informations filled through the view.
If those properties are relatied and corresponded to the list's fields, and they change as long as these fields, then, it's better to make them as other fields of this list.